# How to supply an input value to the prompt via shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a wrapper shell script `wrapper.sh` to run bunch of other already available scripts owned by other people and I cannot touch those scripts.

The problem is, there is one script that runs some db specific activities - `db_perf_clean.sh`. That script is normally executed manually and it prompts for a password at run time. There is no way I can supply the password to it as a parameter and I cannot modify that script. As such I know the db password and I can provide it in `wrapper.sh`.

Please let me know how can I run that `db_perf_clean.sh` script inside `wrapper.sh` like in a silent mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes a script will insist that a password be read from the tty.  Often, it will read from stdin.  If so, try:

```
echo password | db_perf_clean.sh
```

The above has the disadvantage that the password will appear in `ps`.  To avoid that, hide the password in a file and use that file for stdin:

```
db_perf_clean.sh <file_with_password
```

If you want the command to be silent, you can throwaway its output:

```
db_perf_clean.sh <file_with_password >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Under bash, as opposed to generic shell, that can be slightly simplified:

```
db_perf_clean.sh <file_with_password &>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out little different approach instead of writing a password in a file and that worked too ->

```
db_pass="somevalue"
sh db_perf_clean.sh<<EOM
$db_pass
EOM
```